How do I enter and exit positions in my Pine Script strategy?
Here is the code below. I created a signal and tested it with the @study feature. I am trying to selectively open a long (buy) and close the long (sell) based upon the value of signal.
It does not seem to open any positions (or close the only one that is open). How does pine script execute for strategies?
//@version=4
strategy("revers demo")
smaClose = sma(close-open, 1)
doublePrimeClose = sma(smaClose - smaClose[1],15)
digit = 0.0
for c = 1 to 60
    if (sma(close-open, c) > 0 and sma(close-open, c)[1] < 0)
        digit := digit + 1
    if (sma(close-open, c) < 0 and sma(close-open, c)[1] > 0 and  sma(smaClose - smaClose[1], c + 15) > 0)
        digit := digit - 1

signal = digit
if(signal > 8)
    strategy.entry("Buy1", strategy.long, 1, when=signal > 8)
    strategy.exit("bracket", when=signal < -7)

    //strategy.exit("buy", "buy",  1, when=(smaClose < 0 and smaClose[1] > 0 and doublePrimeClose > 0))

    //strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short, 1, when=signal <= -9)
plot(strategy.equity)

PS: I have tried many variations of strategy.open and strategy.exit and none seem to work the way I expect them to.

Your strategy.entry() works. Your problem is you never close your position.
You should use strategy.exit() when you want to close your position at some price level (TP, SL etc.).
It looks like you want to close your position based on a condition. In this case, you should use strategy.close().
You also have a logic issue.
if(signal > 8)
    strategy.entry("Buy1", strategy.long, 1, when=signal > 8)
    strategy.exit("bracket", when=signal < -7)

Your strategy.exit() will never be executed because you will only enter in this if branch if signal > 8. However, to execute your strategy.exit(), you have a condition of signal < -7. These two can never be true at the same time.
Once you figure out your exit condition, just call it like below.
if (signal < -7)
    strategy.close("Buy1")


Yes, this worked for me. Thanks.
